# Ambiguous behaviour in Java synchronization

Tags: java, synchronization

We have a Java web application which connects to CRM through web services. The CRM have a constraint for maximum rate of requests, so we implement a synchronized block in order to make sure that our application should not exceed the CRM maximum rate of requests. When server is up, initially it works, but gradually it stops communicate with CRM. The log says it doesn't enter the synchronized block.

According to the Java specification anything happens (unexpected termination of thread) inside the synchronized block, it releases the lock. So I wonder what may leads to this issue. A code extract is given below.

```
class ConnectToCrm {
...
public send(){
...
 synchronized (ConnectToCrm.class) {
    Thread.sleep(50);
    os = url_con.getOutputStream();
    os.write(data);
    os.flush();
    url_con.connect();
    rc = url_con.getResponseCode();
   }
...
 }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using try-with-resources on that Outputstream? Please also show Exception handling.

Comment: Have you tried monitoring the application for deadlocks?

Comment: Yes, I have modified the code extract.

Comment: Do you use the same connection for all requests? I can't see that you handle it. If so, the connection might be closed by the other side and you will never know it since you always swallow exceptions

Comment: You say that "gradually, it stops"... Does that mean that the throughput decreases, or that it stops working after a certain time? How long is that time? Does the CRM system accept only one connection at the time?

Comment: Do not swallow Exceptions silently! If you catch them - log them at the very least!

Comment: All the resources which are used to communicate with CRM are local variables of "send" method and its closed properly in finally block.

Comment: Synchronization and sleeping is a strange way to do rate-limiting. You should have a timer-task reading from a queue at the required interval.

Comment: What's the rate limit of the CRM. If it's less than 20 Req / s than the CRM will block. What happens if the CRM runs into a request limit? Does it refuse the connection? Does it simply take a long time to answer? Are you sure you've received an answer for the request before the CRM stops communicating?